# MariaDB If statement with select and update query

Tags: sql, if-statement, mariadb

I want to query from a table the row with the latest dtRequestToLog, to get the column strUniqueID. Compare the strUniqueID with an IF Statement, if that is equal to number X, then update in the same row blnAcceptedToLog = 1

So to get the row with the latest dtRequestToLog i use:

```
select strUniqueID from tblmainmonitor t where dtRequestToLog >= (now() - interval 30 minute ) AND idxBedrijf = 1 order by dtRequestToLog asc limit 1
```

This works fine. I have the following if statement that works as well:

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE PROCEDURE pr()
BEGIN
    IF 3 = 3 THEN 
       SELECT 'TRUE';
    ELSE
       SELECT 'FALSE';
    END IF;
END $
DELIMITER ;
CALL pr;
```

So instead of 3 = 3, i want to use the first query, the return value of it compare it to number x, i put in the query dynamicly from code; But when I put the query after 'IF' it would not work, nor with braces.

Then if the statement is true; I would like to use the same found row to update blnAcceptedLog to 1;

How do I do this?

Or should I use an UPDATE query where ((subquery).strUniqueID == 1)? Where the subquery is the first query described at the top. How do I write this?

Edit: Some sample data of tblmainmonitor

```
idxMain|idxBedrijf|strUniqueId|dtLastLog            |dtRequestToLog      |blnAcceptedToLog
1               1   1          2021-07-08 10:00:00   2021-07-08 08:00:00    1
2               1   1                                2021-07-08 14:50:00    0
3               1   2                                2021-07-08 14:51:00    0
```

Comment: Please edit your question adding some sample data

Comment: I added a sample table

Comment: And what is desired result with that sample of data? *then update in the same row* ... update to what value?

Comment: Recommend using a `UPDATE` statement with a `WHERE` criteria. If you're selecting something to update, use `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` and wrap both the `SELECT` and `UPDATE` in a transaction. Avoid the use of procedures for things that can easily be done in application code.

Comment: As to what I want it to update: I would like to use the same found row to update blnAcceptedLog to 1;